# Pagination in Python for API from Solr

Tags: python, solr

I am using Python to extract data from a Solr API, like so:

```
import requests

user = 'my_username'
password= 'my password'
url = 'my_url'

print ("Accessing API..")
req = requests.get(url = url, auth=(user, password))
print ("Accessed!")
out = req.json()
#print(out)
```

However, it looks like in some of the API URLs: the output is fairly "large" (many of the columns are lists of dictionaries), and so it doesn't return all rows, which are necessary.

From looking around, it looks like I should use pagination to bring in results in specified increments. Something like this:

```
url = 'url?start=0&rows=1000'
```

Then,

```
 url = 'url?start=1000&rows=1000'
```

and so on, until there is no result is returned.

The way I am thinking about it is write a loop, and append result to output with every loop. However, I am not sure how to do that.

Would someone be able to help please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Solr has [an export endpoint for retrieving large resultsets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/exporting-result-sets.html). Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the output? In my experience, solr response usually includes a 'numFound' in it's result. On a (old) solr I have locally, doing a random query. I get this result.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "indent": "true",
      "start": "0",
      "rows": "10",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1509460751164"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 7023,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [.. 10 docs]
    }
}
```

While working out this code example, I realized you don't need the `numFound` really. Solr will just return any empty list for `docs` if there are no further results. Making it easier to make the loop.

```
import requests

user = 'my_username'
password = 'my password'

# Starting values
start = 0
rows = 1000  # static, but easier to manipulate if it's a variable
base_url = 'my_url?rows={0}?start={1}'

url = base_url.format(rows, start)
req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user, password))
out = req.json()

total_found = out.get('response', {}).get('numFound', 0)

# Up the start with 1000, so we fetch the next 1000
start += rows


results = out.get('response', {}).get('docs', [])
all_results = results

# Results will be an empty list if no more results are found
while results:
    # Rebuild url base on current start.
    url = base_url.format(rows, start)
    req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user, password))
    out = req.json()
    results = out.get('response', {}).get('docs', [])
    all_results += results
    start += rows

# All results will now contains all the 'docs' of each request.
print(all_results)
```

Mind you.. those docs will be dict like, so more parsing will be needed.

Comment: Hi Pjot, thank you for your reply. I am all good on the parsing end!
As per out.get('response') it is 'other' for me, however I don't seem to have 'docs'... can you let me know what it actually represents, perhaps it is named differently on my end?
I have: {u'other': {u'numFound': 1424, u'resultLength': 5266138, u'timerLogs': {u'aslBmsEstimated': 385, u'aslSolrElapsedTime': 7116, u'aslTotalElapsedTime': 7126, u'aslQueryTime': 7511}

Comment: For me this is the output: { "resultList": [ { },{ } ], "other": { } }. Where "other" includes the numFound variables you mentioned and actual response (I am assuming your 'docs') is out["resultList"]. I got it to work by changing to url?start={0}?rows={1}', and substituting out.get('response', {}).get('docs', []) with out.get('resultList', {}). However, for some reason print(len(all_results)) prior to the loop gives 1000, which makes sense, however, after the loop it prints 2000- but there are 5700+ in the numFound.. Any idea why it doesnt loop through all the way?

Comment: Ugh, just needed to change url= to base_url.format(start, rows) and put start+= row at beginning of loop (so it doesnt start from 0 index) and it worked. Thanks alot!